# Temporary freezes even on small load

Tags: performance, hardware-rec, benchmarking

I have the following setup:

```
ASUS B360M-E TUF Aura Sync
Intel Core i7-9700K 4.9GHz
16GB DDR4 3000 MHz Dual channel memory
NVidia GeForce GTX 1660 6GB DDR5
500GB SSD Western Digital Blue
Chieftec E85 500W
```

I am experiencing temporary freezes/very slow performance sometimes which lasts for  5-10 secs. I tried windows and linux as well. It happens even if I am just looking at a text file, but happens less frequently on small load. I am trying to determine whenever this is hardware fail -, or hardware configuration issue; or somehow software or malware. I tried memory test, and benchmark tests, all looks fine.. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Do some SMART tests on your hard disks.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out the issue was with the Kingston SSD firmware. Needed update to Firmware Revision 605ABBF0 – August 28, 2015. I assume that issue was: 520ABBF0 - Resolved a race condition where a write command during SATA, error handling process could cause drive to hang.
After that works like a charm.